# Prevent iframe from keeping focus using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, focus, embed

**Background:**

I'm helping an old friend who has a mixed media slideshow, and one of the slides is an iframe embed of a lytro camera image (it's interactive and you can click or tap on mobile to change the focus).

**Issue:**

The issue that I'm having is that when you interact with the iframe, it steals keyboard focus on desktops and that prevents the arrow keys from allowing you to change slides.

**What I've tried:**

My main attack angle on this had been trying to use jquery to set a timer that periodically sets focus on the parent document, to remove focus from the iframe and allow the keystrokes to be captured properly. I've noticed that if I click anywhere outside of the iframe then I can use the arrow keys properly.

Here's my jquery code, along with comments about why I tried each method. Unfortunatly nothing has worked (I've also tried including the lytro image with an embed tag instead of the iframe tag with no change in results).

```
<script>
    //make sure body maintains focus, so that swipe and arrows still work
    function focusit(){
        $('#focushere').focus(); // this is a div on the main page that I tried to set focus to
        $('body').focus(); // tried moving focus to the body
        $('embed').blur(); // tried bluring the embed
        $('iframe').blur(); // tried bluring the iframe
        $('body').click(); // tried faking a click on the body 
        $('#focushere').click(); //tried faking a click on a element 
        $(document).click(); // tried click on document
        $(document).focus(); //tried setting focus to document
    }
    setTimeout(focusit, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: I believe that browsers only allow you to change the window focus in response to a user event (such as a click or keyboard event). That's why your time-out approach doesn't work. Unfortunately, I don't know what the best solution is for your situation.

Comment: @Thayne As far as I can tell, setting the focus outside of a user event works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be two-fold.

1. You are using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) which will only run your callback once. I think you mean to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval), which will repeatedly run the callback.
2. You can't set focus to `document` using the `focus` method natively or in jQuery. In order to restore focus to the `body`, you should call the [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.blur) method on the currently active element using [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement).

**Example:**

```
function focusit(){
    if(document.activeElement)
    {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
}
setInterval(focusit, 100);
```

**[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/alexanderomara/pen/rJGFt)**

Comment: Much thanks! I was using setInterval initially and changed it while copy-pasting code that I didn't look at carefully enough, that plus document.activeElement.blur() did the trick.